# In a Tcl script line, It it is possible to write 2 or more commands?

Tags: tcl

Each tcl script line is one command.  Is there any kind of tcl-newline-script-string, so that putting it to a tcl script line, the tcl interpreter will treat the tcl script line as two commands?

Example, if ^ is such tcl-newline-script-string, for a tcl script line:

```
puts "a" ^ puts "b"
```

I expect the tcl interpreter will treat it as

```
puts "a"
puts "b"
```

I am looking for such tcl-newline-script-string.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for semicolon:

```
puts "a"; puts "b"
```

The semicolon basically tells the interpreter that the command has reached an end, so you can start another one.

Comment: This is also how you put a comment after a command: `puts "a"; # print string a to stdout`

Comment: Semicolon works exactly like newline. It's usually thought of as **good style** to not use it very much. My main use is for `; #` so I can do on-the-same-line comments.